# check mount point status using monit service

Tags: monitoring, monit

I would like to monitor the server "**mount point status**" using "**monit**".

**Check filesystem** is available to check whether that filesystem available or not on the systeam. But couldn't check filesystem mount point.Please correct me if its wrong. Since I tested this check locally , its not check the filesystem mount point, it checks only filesystem attached to server or not.

For some reason, my mount on the server getting disconnected frequently. so I would like to get an alert whenever mount gets disconnected.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a flag file (here server-nfs-a) located on the mounted point

```
check file mount-flag-nas-b with path /mount/NAS-A/server-nfs-a
      if does not exist then exec "/bin/mount /mount/NAS-A" else if succeeded then exec "/var/lib/monit/scripts/notifySuccess.sh"
```

Here I prefer to mount it when the file cannot be found due to missing mount.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script called *test-mount.sh* to test mount. I am using file create and delete as I find just reading a file unreliable.

```
set -e
/bin/touch /my-mounted-dir/test/mount.test
/bin/rm /my-mounted-dir/test/mount.test
exit 0
```

1. set -e tells the script to stop execution and return error if any
   command fails.
2. Use touch to create a file.
3. Remove the file.
4. exit 0 will tell monit script succeeded.

Create test on monit config. This will run the test-mount.sh and if it fails it will run remount-data.sh. You can replace this with anything you want to do in case of a failed mount.

```
    check program test-mount with path /root/test-mount.sh timeout 5 seconds 
      if status != 0 then exec "/root/remount-data.sh"
```